# Error 1022 en SQL llave duplicada

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo usando `SQL` y estaba construyendo el siguiente script:

```
CREATE TABLE EventRequest (EventNo varchar(8) not null,
                           DateHeld date not null,
                           DateReq date not null,
                           CustNo varchar (8) not null,
                           FacNo varchar(8) not null,
                           DateAuth date,
                           Status varchar(10) not null,
                           EstCost varchar (10) not null,
                           EstAudience varchar (10) not null,
                           Budno varchar (20),
                           CONSTRAINT EstAudienceValid check (EstAudience > 0),
                           CONSTRAINT ValidStatus check (Status in ('Pending','Denied','Approved')),
                           CONSTRAINT PK_EventRequest PRIMARY KEY (EventNo),
                           CONSTRAINT FK_CustNo FOREIGN KEY (CustNo) REFERENCES Customer (CustNo),
                           CONSTRAINT FK_FacNo FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Facility (FacNo)
                           );
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale este error:

> Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'EventRequest'

Sinceramente no sé dónde está el error, sé que es en una llave, ¿pero en cuál?

Answer (score 1):

Probé crear esta misma consulta sin las llaves foráneas y se creó la tabla normalmente, lo más probable es que el error esté cuando realizas las llaves foráneas ya que tu indicas *FK_CustNo* y *FK_FacNo* que puede ser que ya estén registrados en otras tablas, para esto puedes usar una nomenclatura fk_NombreColumna_NombreTabla (en tu caso *FK_CustNo_EventRequest*). Pruébalo y si te sirve agradecería tu respuesta. Saludos!